# JavaFX - Unable to access file system with signed app

Tags: java, security, javafx-2

I am developing a JavaFX application that needs to access files on the users system. I know that my application must be signed before it could have such access, so i signed my app. But the app still throws java.security.AccessControlException

-The  Application

```
public class TestApp extends Application
{
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
         primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!"); 
         StackPane root = new StackPane();
         primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
         primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void callJSFunc(JSObject func) 
    {
         File fleExample = new File("F:/myfile.xml");
         func.call("call", fleExample.exists());
    }
}
```

Then i went on to sign the app

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias me  
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore TestApp.jar me
```

So i called the apps **callJSFunc** from javascript

```
function deployIt() 
{
      dtjava.embed(
      {
          id: "my2",
          url: "TestApp.jnlp",
          width: 300,
          height: 200,
          placeholder: "here"
       },
       { 
          javafx: "2.1+", 
           jvm: "1.6.0+" 
       },
       {
           onJavascriptReady: callApp
       });
}

function callApp(id) 
{
   var app = document.getElementById(id);
   app.callJSFunc(function(e){ alert(e); });
}

dtjava.addOnloadCallback(deployIt);
```

But my app outputed this on the browser

```
Uncaught Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "F:/myfile.xml" "read")
```

Also, i tested the app on my localhost. I don't understand why its throwing this exception after siging the app. Please what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the keytool and jarsigner to sign the app.

Instead package, sign and ready your app for deployment using the [javafx deployment tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) such as javafxpackager or the JavaFX ant tasks.

Make sure that your [jnlp file requests elevated permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#security).  If you are using the JavaFX ant tasks, you can request JavaFX to generate an appropriate jnlp with elevated permissions using a [fx:permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIAHGJBH) clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with a doPrivileged block) :

```
public class TestApp extends Application
{
    // ...

    public void callJSFunc(JSObject func) 
    {
         File fleExample = null;
         AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                fleExample = new File("F:/myfile.xml");
                func.call("call", fleExample.exists());
            }
         });

    }
}
```