# XSLT transformation of xml file in JavaFX with Saxon-HE

Tags: java, xml, xslt, javafx, saxon

I am building a small application where I open an `XML` file and display it in a `TextArea` in JavaFX. Then I call a method that points to a local `XSL` file that carries out the transformation to a simple `HTML` output. In the end, I want to display the transformed XML into a new popup window (load another `.fxml` file).

So I have one `RootLayout.fxml`  and a respective `RootLayoutController` which handles the transform call. The RootLayout is simple and only handles Menu operations (Open File, Transform) and initiates another FXML. The TextArea is contained in this other FXML file `editorOverview`:

```
@FXML
private void handleTransform() {
    String xslt = "main.xsl"; // the path is reduced only here for simplicity
    String source = src.MainApp.editorOverviewController.XMLtextArea.getText();
    String result = "";
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try {    
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslt)));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringBufferInputStream(source)), new StreamResult(result));

        src.MainApp.TransformViewController.resultTextArea.setText(result);
        src.MainApp.TransformViewController.showResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I am trying to assign the result of the transformation to an empty string `result` and then set the text of the text area in the `TransformView.fxml` to the value of `result. After that, I want to show this window.

And in my `TransformViewController` I have the `showResult()` method :

```
public void showResult() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TransformView.fxml"));
        Parent htmlView = (Parent) loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("HTML Result");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(htmlView));
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TransformViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)
; SystemID: 
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)
```

Is the error related to the way I do the transformation? (For the record, the transformation is successfully executed in a oXygen XML Developer with Saxon-HE 9.5, the same that I have included in my project as a jar)

Any ideas/suggestions are well appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Stacktrace:

```
Error on line 33 of main.xsl:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\NetBeansProjects\editor
  (Access is denied)
; SystemID: file:/C:/XSLT/main.xsl; Line#: 33; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\NetBeansProjects\editor (Access is denied)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:198)    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:198)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeWriter(Emitter.java:160)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.openDocument(XMLEmitter.java:145)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.characters(XMLEmitter.java:570)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLIndenter.indent(XMLIndenter.java:311)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLIndenter.startElement(XMLIndenter.java:111)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startElement(NamespaceReducer.java:73)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startContent(ComplexContentOutputter.java:558)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startElement(ComplexContentOutputter.java:183)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:424)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:660)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:138)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:431)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:239)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1057)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2088)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1911)
    at uimlbuddy.view.RootLayoutController.handleTransform(RootLayoutController.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\NetBeansProjects\editor (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:192)
    ... 80 more
---------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\NetBeansProjects\editor (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:192)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeWriter(Emitter.java:160)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.openDocument(XMLEmitter.java:145)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.characters(XMLEmitter.java:570)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLIndenter.indent(XMLIndenter.java:311)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLIndenter.startElement(XMLIndenter.java:111)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startElement(NamespaceReducer.java:73)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startContent(ComplexContentOutputter.java:558)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startElement(ComplexContentOutputter.java:183)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:424)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:660)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:138)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:431)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:239)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1057)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2088)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1911)
    at uimlbuddy.view.RootLayoutController.handleTransform(RootLayoutController.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The stack trace will tell you which line in your program the error comes from. That's the first thing we need to know to help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the whole stacktrace. What baffles me is that on top it says there is an error with the xslt file. But at the same time when I execute the very same xslt against the very same xml file outside of my project with the same saxon-he 9.5.1.5 version I get no errors. This is why I though that maybe I am doing something wrong with the transformer itself.

Comment: Does your application have permissions to access the file system? Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11882586/241294.

Comment: The application is signed alright, and I also have a method that can save files to the file system via FileChooser and that works fine. Unless these are not related?

Comment: Ok, the error comes from the fact that when I use `new File()`, I am supposed to give a file name. And I assign it to an empty string instead (`result`). How can I assign the result of the transformation to this empty string? In other words, do I really need to create a new file? I would like to store the result in the `result` empty string and then set it's value into the TextArea from the second view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the result of a transformation as a string, do

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
```

Specify `result` as the destination of the transformation (second arg to `transform()`), and on completion, `sw.toString()` will contain the serialized transformation result.

Comment: I figured it out earlier today. Nevertheless, thank you for the time!